# How to prevent css reanimation on calendar click

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to do some animation on a ASP calendar, using CSS and Jquery. I Hide the calendar using CSS and when some events occur, I just fadein. The calendar is inside an AJAX update panel. My problem comes when I click on one day in the calendar. The CSS seem to restart and hide the calendar and the Jquery (of course) does not fadein. What I want is to avoid hidding the calendar on click. Ive tried many thing, none works. Here is part of my code:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(
function ()
{
  ...
  var invoiceB = $(".invoiceBtnPos"); 
  invoiceB.animate({ left: '92%' }, 1500,
        function () {
            var UserCalendarC = $("#UserCalendar");

            UserCalendarC.fadeIn({ duration: 1500 });

            UserCalendarC.classList.remove("DHidden");
        });     
   });
```

CSS

```
.DHidden { display:none; }
```

ASPX

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateUserPanel" runat="server">
        <contenttemplate>
            <fieldset class="ZeroDecoration">
             ...
                    <asp:Calendar ID="UserCalendar"  ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="Calendar DHidden" DayNameFormat="Full" ShowGridLines="True" Width="26%" Height="425px" 
                        OnDayRender="UserCalendar_DayRender" NextMonthText="<img src='../Images/nextimg.png' border='0' width='60%' height='auto'>" 
                        PrevMonthText="<img src='../Images/previmg.png' border='0' width='60%' height='auto'>" OnSelectionChanged="UserCalendar_SelectionChanged" >
                        <DayHeaderStyle CssClass="DayHeaderStyle" />
                        <DayStyle CssClass="DayStyle no_underline" ForeColor="White" />
                        <WeekendDayStyle CssClass="WeekendDayStyle no_underline" />
                        <NextPrevStyle CssClass="NextPrevStyle"  />
                        <OtherMonthDayStyle CssClass="OtherMonthDayStyle no_underline" />
                        <SelectedDayStyle CssClass="SelectedDayStyle no_underline" />
                        <SelectorStyle CssClass="SelectorStyle" />
                        <TitleStyle CssClass="TitleStyle" />
                        <TodayDayStyle CssClass="TodayDayStyle no_underline" />
                    </asp:Calendar>  
              ...
            </fieldset>
        </contenttemplate>            
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

CS

```
protected void UserCalendar_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{            
    e.Cell.Text += e.Day.DayNumberText;
    e.Cell.ToolTip = e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString();
    e.Cell.Attributes.Add("OnClick",e.SelectUrl);
}

protected void UserCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   currentDate.Text = UserCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
}
```

The closest approach I did is to set the display property in Javascript also, at the beginning, but the behavior looks weird (show, hide, then fadein)...

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    var calendar = $("#UserCalendar");

    calendar.css("display", "none");
}
```

Its my first time asking here, sorry for all the mistakes I may have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I fix it the second after post the Question (What stupid I am). I solve it just overriding the css on Selection changed for the calendar, like this:

```
    protected void UserCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserCalendar.CssClass = "Calendar";
        currentDate.Text = UserCalendar.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
    }
```

I know is not the very clean, but for me, it saves the day. Thanks to all who waste their time on my question.